# How to correctly search in Python3 and get the value?

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to read a `.env` style file and pull out the content using regex. The line I want to search and get is:

```
APP_SECRET=test
```

I want to get the `test`. However, when I try search, I get `None`:

```
import re


if "APP_SECRET" in RESPONSE:
    print(re.search('APP_SECRET', RESPONSE)) #None
```

`RESPONSE` does have `APP_SECRET=test` in. Any help appreciated.

I assign response like so:

```
RESPONSE = REQ.get(f"{NBASE}/download?file={DATA['file']}&c={DATA['c']}").text
```

Comment: how are you assigning `RESPONSE`?

Comment: I updated question, didn't realise it was important. It is just a string with `APP_SECRET=test` from PHP `file_get_contents()` @EdoAkse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read through each line of the response and split on `=` and check if the left side has "APP_SECRET", like

```
for line in RESPONSE.split('\n'):
    params = line.split('=')
    if params[0] == 'APP_SECRET':
        val = params[1]
        break
print(val)
```